# Proving $1+\frac{3}{a+b+c}\geq \frac{6}{ab+bc+ca}$, given $abc=1$

Tags: inequality

Let a, b, c be positive numbers such that $abc=1$. Prove that $1+\frac{3}{a+b+c}\geq \frac{6}{ab+bc+ca}$

The usual methods do not seem to work, including a substitution $a=\frac{x}{y}, b=\frac{y}{z}, c=\frac{z}{x}$ and trying to apply Muirhead's inequality.

Comment: Muirhead wouldn't work (directly) since the transformation makes the inequality non-symmetric.

Comment: I tried to prove the resulting non-symmetric inequality, without success. I also tried to not apply substitutions but get rid of the fractions and then homogenize the resulting inequality (since abc=1). Got nowhere.

Answer (score 6):

We have $(ab+bc+ca)^2 \geq 3 (a+b+c)abc $, which is equivalent to $ (ab-bc)^2 + (bc-ca)^2 + (ca-ab)^2 \geq 0$. Hence,

$$ 1 + \frac{3}{a+b+c} \geq 2 \sqrt{ \frac{3}{a+b+c} } \geq \frac{6}{ab+bc+ca}. $$

Comment: This is a great simple solution which has eluded me for days.

Answer (score 2):

$$\Longleftrightarrow (ab+bc+ac)+\dfrac{3(ab+bc+ac)}{a+b+c}\ge 6$$
since by $AM-GM$ inequality
$$ (ab+bc+ac)+\dfrac{3(ab+bc+ac)}{a+b+c}\ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{3(ab+bc+ac)^2}{a+b+c}}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow2\sqrt{\dfrac{3(ab+bc+ac)^2}{a+b+c}}\ge 6$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (ab+bc+ac)^2\ge 3(a+b+c)$$
since by $AM-GM$
$$(ab+bc+ac)^2\ge 3abc(a+b+c)=3(a+b+c)$$
By Done.

Comment: This is identical to mine.